# Most efficient language to create a very fast web crawler?

Tags: web-crawler

I am working on creating a new website which recommends links for a category. I need to scan different web pages quickly. Which language should I work on to create an efficient web crawler?

Comment: Efficient in what sense? For you or for the computer?

Answer (score 3):

Use what you know.  Find the libraries for your current preferred language for doing crawling/scraping, and then only optimise to a new language once you are hitting bottlenecks.

If you use Python, then the stdlib has plenty enough html text extraction for basic stuff, and then if you need more complexity, try beautifulsoup (note: use bs4, it's better than bs3).

Ideally, you should be doing your scraping/crawling in the background, and writing caches somehow to a local database.  Say MariaSql, Postgres, Sqlite (up to a million or so pages), or one of the NoSQL solutions.

If you do this, and the format you're storing in is reasonably standard, then you can easily replace the code, or the language you're using later on.

You can then leave the front-facing web code in whatever you prefer - php, python, whatever, and then swap in a new more efficient back end crawler.  If you need it.